# (PySpark) Nested lists after reduceByKey

Tags: python, apache-spark

I'm sure this is something very simple but I didn't find anything related to this.

My code is simple:

```
... 
stream = stream.map(mapper) 
stream = stream.reduceByKey(reducer) 
...
```

Nothing extraordinary.The output looks like this:

```
... 
key1  value1 
key2  [value2, value3] 
key3  [[value4, value5], value6] 
...
```

And so on. So, sometimes I got a flat value (if it's single). Sometimes - nested lists that might be really, really deep (on my simple test data it was 3 levels deep).

I tried searching through sources for something like 'flat' - but found only flatMap method which is (as I understand it) not what I need.

I don't know why those lists are nested. My guess is that they were handled by different processes (workers?) and then joined together without flattening.

Of course, I can write a code in Python which will unfold that list and flatten it. But I believe this is not a normal situation - I think almost everybody needs a flat output.

itertools.chain stops unfolding on fist found non-iterable value. In other words, it still needs some coding (previous paragraph).

So - how to flatten the list using PySpark's native methods?

Thanks

Comment: What's your reduce function (`reducer`)?

Comment: @JoshRosen just "return [key, value]"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem here is your reduce function.  For each key, `reduceByKey` calls your reduce function with pairs of values and expects it to produce combined values of the same type.

For example, say that I wanted to perform a word count operation.  First, I can map each word to a `(word, 1)` pair, then I can `reduceByKey(lambda x, y: x + y)` to sum up the counts for each word.  At the end, I'm left with an RDD of `(word, count)` pairs.

Here's an example from the [PySpark API Documentation](https://spark.incubator.apache.org/docs/0.8.1/api/pyspark/pyspark.rdd.RDD-class.html#reduceByKey):

```
>>> from operator import add
>>> rdd = sc.parallelize([("a", 1), ("b", 1), ("a", 1)])
>>> sorted(rdd.reduceByKey(add).collect())
[('a', 2), ('b', 1)]
```

To understand why your example didn't work, you can imagine the reduce function being applied something like this:

```
reduce(reduce(reduce(firstValue, secondValue), thirdValue), fourthValue) ...
```

Based on your reduce function, it sounds like you might be trying to implement the built-in [`groupByKey`](https://spark.incubator.apache.org/docs/0.8.1/api/pyspark/pyspark.rdd.RDD-class.html#groupByKey) operation, which groups each key with a list of its values.

Also, take a look at [`combineByKey`](https://spark.incubator.apache.org/docs/0.8.1/api/pyspark/pyspark.rdd.RDD-class.html#combineByKey), a generalization of `reduceByKey()` that allows the reduce function's input and output types to differ (`reduceByKey` is [implemented](https://spark.incubator.apache.org/docs/0.8.1/api/pyspark/pyspark.rdd-pysrc.html#RDD.reduceByKey) in terms of `combineByKey`)

Comment: ouch... I must say, Spark's approach differs from many MR frameworks. It takes some time to port some working MRJob or Disco code there.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, `stream.groupByKey().mapValues(lambda x: list(x)).collect()` gives

```
key1 [value1]
key2 [value2, value3]
key3 [value4, value5, value6]
```

Comment: or just `.groupByKey().mapValues(list)`

Comment: or `.reduceByKey(lambda a,b: (a if type(a) == list else [a]) + (b if type(b) == list else [b])).collect()`