# is it more efficient to use unions rather than joins in apache spark, or does it not matter?

Tags: python, performance, join, mapreduce, apache-spark

Recently I was running a job on an apache spark cluster and I was going to do an inner join on two rdds.  However I then thought that for this calculation I could avoid a join by using union, reduceByKey and filter instead.  But is this basically what join is already doing under the hood?

say I have objects in rdd's that have the following structure:

> { 'key':'someKey', 'value': <some positive integer> }

Then to avoid the join I'd write:

```
leftRDD = rdd1.map(lambda y: (y['key'], (1, y['value'], -1))
rightRDD = rdd2.map(lambda y: (y['key'], (0, -1, y['value']))
joinedRDD = (leftRDD + rightRDD) \
    .reduceByKey(lambda x,y: (max(x[0],y[0]), max(x[1],y[1]), max(x[2],y[2])) \
    .filter(lambda y: y[1][0] == 1)
```

joinedRDD would now effectively have the same result as if I'd done an inner join, but is the added complexity worth it to avoid the join?

Comment: I cannot speak for PySpark, but in general Spark both `join` and `reduceByKey` will perform a shuffle if necessary. Your proposed alternative has no reason to be faster. The only way to be sure, however, is to ask some random people on Stack Overflow to guess! I'm kidding. The way to be sure is to benchmark this. It should be really simple to check.

Comment: @Daniel Well I figured I'd start with SO first and benchmark 2nd :)

Comment: @DanielDarabos This "random" SOF has looked at (source code) and used both pyspark and native scala versions in the past. The differences are being noted /updated in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pyspark joins are often poor at scalability - so your hunch at manual RDD operations is likely a good one.

In particular joins in pyspark lose the partitioning - so copartioned joins are not supported.

For the specifics: you should be careful on the semantics of reduceByKey: it outputs the *same* data structure as the input. You may be expecting something different based on your code.

Take a look at [(PySpark) Nested lists after reduceByKey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21077103/pyspark-nested-lists-after-reducebykey) for more info on reduceByKey.

**UPDATE**

The native scala version is more aggressive in retaining the existing partitioning (not inducing a full shuffle):

```
if (self.partitioner == Some(partitioner)) {
  self.mapPartitions(iter => {
    val context = TaskContext.get()
    new InterruptibleIterator(context, aggregator.combineValuesByKey(iter, context))
  }, preservesPartitioning = true)
} else {
  new ShuffledRDD[K, V, C](self, partitioner)
    .setSerializer(serializer)
    .setAggregator(aggregator)
    .setMapSideCombine(mapSideCombine)
}
```

Instead the python version ALWAYS induces a shuffle:

```
    shuffled = locally_combined.partitionBy(numPartitions)
```

It is for this reason that I had noted the performance concern on pyspark with reduceByKey.

The overall 'answer' is not a clear cut yes or no: I was saying it "could be yes" - depends on how you write the custom pyspark RDD code vs just using join() - which always induces a shuffle.

Comment: Are you talking only about pyspark or spark in general?

Comment: pyspark in particular

Comment: Is this a yes or a no for the original question?

Comment: @user52045 It's about apache spark generally (unless there's some specific difference between spark and pyspark?)

Comment: well, my suggestion would be use sql if possible, as catalyst optimizer often generates plan as good as hand tuned ones (claimed)